# Priority or Disable Sources?

Tags: google-fit-api

I have a user where if I upload data to their account, I get a successful message back from Google Fit, but I cannot that data back from the aggregated feeds nor does the user see the data in the Google Fit app.

For example, the upload of:

```
{"dataSourceId":"raw:com.google.step_count.delta:132640741942","minStartTimeNs":1590015600000000000,"maxEndTimeNs":1590102000000000000,"point":[{"endTimeNanos":1590020944666000000,"dataTypeName":"com.google.step_count.delta","startTimeNanos":1590015600000000000,"value":[{"intVal":18102}]}]}
```

Results as

```
{"minStartTimeNs":"1590015600000000000","maxEndTimeNs":"1590102000000000000","dataSourceId":"raw:com.google.step_count.delta:132640741942","point":[{"startTimeNanos":"1590015600000000000","endTimeNanos":"1590020944666000000","dataTypeName":"com.google.step_count.delta","value":[{"intVal":18102,"mapVal":[]}]}]}
```

But a read does not contain this information.  I cannot reproduce this on other accounts.  Is there a way to disable DataSources?

Eric

Comment: In looking at this more, the aggregated "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps" request results in 0.  Reading the actual data source id written shows the proper value.  Why is this?  How can I prevent it?